Why is my ExecStart failing?
My docker.service
[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutStartSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

I got
сеп 02 13:53:48 jh systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
сеп 02 13:53:48 jh systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
сеп 02 13:53:48 jh systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.

What does this mean
-H fd://

how to solve this?
EDIT
I saw this
https://forums.docker.com/t/failing-to-start-dockerd-failed-to-create-nat-chain-docker/78269/6
the same problem persists
journalctl -xeu docker.service

gave me
systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.

I installed Docker
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh

after cleaning the previous,Ubuntu 22.04 install.

This question is similar to: Why crontab doesn't execute a scheduled bash script?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
